# When we click the out of application then popup is not closed

Tags: xml, wpf

When we click the out of application then popup is not closed.

In WPF, when we click the out of application then popup should be Closed but when we click the inside the application then popup should not be closed.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: <Popup  IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=BtnNote}" StaysOpen="True" Width="Auto"                           RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=popupshow}"                             HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Placement="RelativePoint"                               x:Name="NotePopup" HorizontalOffset="0" VerticalOffset="0" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=MainWindowWpf, Mode=OneTime}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
                                                  
<!-- Code -->
</popup>

Comment: Set StaysOpen="False"

Comment: if I set StayOpen="False"  then  when I click inside the application then popup is closed.

Comment: Do this in Window's LostFocus.

Comment: It is working. Thank you.

Comment: create event on Window's LostFocus  write this code inside the event :-this.uc_ClientManager.NotePopup.IsOpen = false;. but when i click on popup then popup is also closed. Because that time Window's LostFocus event is call.